# How do I write "when scheduled" for a future appointment?

Tags: gramática, subjuntivo

At my job, I sometimes have to make a list of requirements for Spanish-speaking clients. This list entails certain appointments. For the *"employment assessment"* I also write the phrase *"when scheduled"*.

How do I translate *"when scheduled"*? Would it be *"cuando se programa"* or *"cuando se programe"*? Not sure if I should be using the subjunctive....

---

To be more specific, my clients are applying for temporary assistance. I give them a list of requirements that they must fill in to complete the application. These are usually things they might have to hand in or appointments they might have attend. So, the list might look something like this:

> RESIDENCIA - (declaración de propietario)
>   VERIFICACIÓN DE DESCAPACIDAD - (la forma de evaluación física llenada por su médico)
>   CITA CON IMA - (14 de Mayo, 2014- para evaluación psicológica)
>   EVALUACIÓN DE EMPLEO - (cuando se programe)

But sometimes, depending on the situation, it might be *"si se programe"*. I wrote it in the subjunctive and my supervisor wants me to change it to *"se programa"*.

Comment: I'm a little bit struggling with the context. Could you please edit your question and add a full sentence?

Comment: I agree with Lisa, please provide context. But, it appears "cuando se programe" is correct.

Comment: I agree with Nico, that will be usefull because in fact, the form of the verb is subjunctive but I'm not sure if "cuando se programe" fix totally in the context. For example, I think "cuando se requiera" could be more appropiate...

Comment: In Argentina we use "Fecha a confirmar". It implies that the appointment needs to be confirmed before being published.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest the following corrections to the original translation:

> RESIDENCIA - (declaración **del** propietario)

Here I've corrected a missing article. Although *"propietario"* is a more common word, perhaps [*"arrendador"*](http://www.wordreference.com/es/en/translation.asp?spen=arrendador) is more accurate.

> VERIFICACIÓN DE **DISCAPACIDAD** - (**certificado médico de incapacidad física**)

I've corrected the spelling of *"discapacidad"* and used the usual wording for a *"medical certificate of physical disability"*.

> CITA CON IMA - (14 de Mayo, 2014 - para evaluación psicológica)

I don't know what *"IMA"* is. Everything else looks good to me.

> EVALUACIÓN DE EMPLEO - (cuando se programe)

You could also use the verb *"concertar"* (*"cuando se concierte"*).

Subjuntive is the right translation.

To decide whether subjuntive or indicative follows *"cuando"*, learners of Spanish are usually told that:

- for **future actions**, *"cuando"* is followed by subjuntive:

  > Los participantes recibirán un correo cuando se programe la reunion
  >   *(The attendants will receive an email when the meeting is scheduled)*
- for **habitual actions**, *"cuando"* is followed by indicative:

  > Los participantes reciben un correo cuando se programa una reunion
  >   *(The attendants receive an email when a meeting is scheduled)*
- for **past actions**, *"cuando"* is followed by indicative:

  > Los participantes recibieron un correo cuando se programó la reunion
  >   *(The attendants received an email when the meeting was scheduled)*

Answer (score 0):

Based on the context you've given, there are some other translations that might work as well based on more specific context.

If you are saying that an evaluation is to be scheduled, you can instead of use simply **a programar** or as others have pointed out **a concertar**.

Some other things.  *forma* is wrong, *formulario* or *modelo* is generically better, but here I agree with Nico, it should be *certificado*, but I've always seen just *certificado de discapacidad* sans other words.  Instead of *discapacidad* you can also use *minusvalía* (although these days it's not considered as PC). Also, notice date formatting.  Either *14 mayo 2014* or *14 de mayo de 2014* (all lowercase), or use numerals for the month: *14 VI 2014* or *14-6-2014* or similar.

Another thing to consider is the declaración del propietario.  That's fine if you just need the owner of the proper to certify where they're living.  If you're wanting a copy of a lease or evidence they own it which I suppose you are, I'd use that something like below:

> RESIDENCIA - (contrato de arrendimiento/hipoteca o título inmobiliario)
>
> VERIFICACIÓN DE DISCAPACIDAD - (certificado de discapacidad)
>
> CITA CON IMA - (14 mayo 2014 - para evaluación psicológica)
>
> EVALUACIÓN DE EMPLEO - (a concertar)

For the other text you mention as *si se programa* (I'm guessing in English "if/as necessary") you can use *en su caso*.